# MySQL/PHP; Fetch only attribute fields from a database without rows

Tags: php, mysql, fetch, names

I make a query that give me zero rows (ok: no row meets my select).

Is there a way to fetch only the attribute names, also if there is not any row with data?

```
$row_number = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
     // Fetch just two field names, only the first row fetched
     if ($row_number==0) {
           $desc = $row["DESCRIPTION"];
           $unit = $row["UNIT"];  
    }
// ....
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly :

You can use the metadata provided by mysql in [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html).
There in [COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table you can find out the name , type etc of the columns that you need.

Comment: I wasn't clear, my apologies: I was referring to the contents of two fields always present in a table. My mistake was that I tried to select it from a join query with this table (so it couldn't be fetched if Join give no results). I worked around by adding (before) a select query on that table in order to fetch just these values then make a second query (join) that could give o not rows.